# I want to clear or delete rows with variable values

Tags: excel, vba

I need to delete or clear multiple continuous rows say 29 to 47 but the row depends on the row index. Say row is 29 now, but the next run of the program the row is 47.  I need to take the last row set entered and delete it.  I know the start row and the end row values that I need to delete, but putting in code like Range("S13") to Range("S14")  instead of Range(.(Rows(2),.Rows(20)).Delete Shift:xlup gives me syntax error or other errors depending On what I try.
Any suggestions would be greatly Appreciated

Comment: Try looping from bottom of the rows to the top rather than top to the bottom.

Comment: maybe `Range("S13:S14").entirerow.delete` ? It's hard to be specific since your 'examples' are all over the map.

Comment: Range(.(Rows(2),.Rows(20)).Delete works. If you know the start and end row numbers this is what you should be using. Why isn't this sufficient? Why are you trying to to change it to something else? Where/how are you putting "Range("S13") to Range("S14")"? What else are you trying to do?

Comment: Please show the exact code you are using.  How are "continuous" rows defined?  How is "row index" determined?